# Reinstalling WordPress

Tags: installation

I have WordPress installed on my server. now I was using it almost as a testing install but i put up many posts on it. I added and removed many plugins and themes and tweaked with all the settings. So now I want to do a fresh install of WordPress.

I want a new database and the core. Also I want to install all the plugins and the theme again.

I want to keep my existing posts, with the images. There are just 30 of them, with no comments, and comments are handled by DISQUS. Also, the export file from WordPress, gives me an xml file, but i will put it on the same domain, so i think I wouldn't be able to get those images.

It's ok if the downtime is long, no problem... but I want a fresh install...

So can anyone guide me on how to do this without any errors... Thanks and just for info, my hosting is on GoDaddy...

Answer (score 2):

1. Export the WordPress XML file
2. Create a temporary wordpress.com
   account
3. Import the WordPress XML file
   into the temporary wordpress.com
   account
4. Export the WordPress.com XML file
5. Re-install WordPress, with fresh
   database, etc.
6. Import WordPress.com XML file

Comment: Benett What's the advantage of importing and exporting from WP.com?

Comment: @Chris_O: not having to setup a temporary database, and installing a separate instance of WordPress on one's own server. Doing the import into the separate install will import the attachments, so that when they are re-imported on the original site, they'll be downloaded from the wordpress.com account, rather than from the no-longer-extant site that was blown away/re-installed.

Comment: that's great to know.  Very good tip!